# Bot Framework Chatbot keeps asking user consent in Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have set up a bot with Microsoft Bot Framework and added SSO for Teams according to the following manual:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso-bots

The OAuth App registration has the Api permissions email, offline_access, openid, profile, User.Read and they are Admin Granted. The Teams App is installed in the same tenant as the bot and the OAuth app registration.

However no matter what I try the user in Teams keeps getting the message for additional permissions:
[image]

When clicking Continue the login is successful, however after signing out and logging in again, the exact same message appears.

1. Why is the message there after the api permissions have all been granted?
2. If it says only one time required, why does it keep popping up?

Comment: Can you share some of your code, how you're checking for the existence of the token? There might be something wrong in there, so it's not re-retrieving the token properly in later attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was missing to update the "accessTokenAcceptedVersion" to 2 in the manifest.
[image]